# Simple update && upgrade crontab not working on Ubuntu Server [16.04.2]

Tags: 16.04, server, apt, cron, lts

I'd like to have a crontab run once a day to keep some servers updated.

I thought adding `@daily apt update && apt -y upgrade` to root crontab would work.

Apparently, I've done something wrong because it doesn't seem to update the system?

When I ssh in the motd says there's updates.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Perhaps it needs `sudo`...

Comment: Hi @MichaelBay, it's running on root perms.

Comment: Perhaps you need a better approach, like with `unattended-upgrades`:  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue.  It looks like you need to set the PATH environment variable in order to make apt-get work correctly if it gets called by cron.

Add the following

```
PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
```

See [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/644460/apt-get-y-upgrade-in-cron-task-runs-but-does-not-upgrade-the-system?rq=1) for more details.